# Is there a concept of a ‘realm of secrets’ in any mythology?

Tags: myth-identification

Especially concerned with things such as fate, death, tie, love, is there a metaphysical place that deals specifically with things that humans do not comprehend?

Comment: You might want to look into [sacred mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_mysteries), [mystery religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Roman_mysteries), and the [Eleusinian Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusinian_Mysteries).  I don't know that there were formal realms, excepting the underworld and the heavens.